# Union of sets in a neighborhood system

Tags: general-topology

Looking at the definitions in
[https://www.amazon.com/Infinite-Dimensional-Analysis-Hitchhikers-Guide/dp/3540326960/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1485902922&sr=8-1&keywords=infinite+dimensional+analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540326960)
we can find on page 27 the definition of a neighborhood system to be the collection of all neighborhoods of a point *x* belonging to some topological space **X** with a topology **t**. It suggests that the intersection of any 2 neighborhoods **U** and **V** also belongs to the system of neighborhoods, but nothing is mentioned about unions.

My question to you if the following: if **U** and **V** are neighborhoods of the same point *x*, wouldn't their union also be a neighborhood of *x* and thus belong to the system of neighborhoods?

Comment: I can't see page 27 in the free sample. But anyway, if $U,V$ are neighborhoods of $x$ then the union $U \cup V$ is also a neighborhood of $x$. Actually, the only thing keeping the collection $\mathcal{O}$ of all neighborhoods of $x$ from being a topology on $X$ is the fact that $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{O}$

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer.